# SetroubleshootPrivileged.py using 95% CPU | Centos 8 server

Tags: selinux, centos8

I have been battling with this issue for weeks.
I have a Linode with a Centos 8 server.
An application called "SetroubleshootPrivileged.py" is eating all the resources.

"setroubleshootd" is supposed to log SELinux errors which is great but what is "SetoubleshhotPrivileged.py" and how can I get rid of this issue?

[image]
[image]

I tried to learn more about what could cause this issue but "sudo sealert -a /var/log/audit/audit.log" does not give me anything... just freezes at 4%.

[image]

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

For me running `systemctl status dbus.service` showed that Selinux is preventing some stuff from running.

In the output and also in /var/log/messages I found its suggestions for fixing the issue.

Comment: Nice, thanks! SELinux is preventing php-fpm from writing to PHP files and the websites dir.

Comment: I did the following to fix the access to PHP files:
ausearch -c 'php-fpm' --raw | audit2allow -M my-phpfpm
semodule -X 300 -i my-phpfpm.pp

Just worried that it gives too much permission then nothing is protected?

Comment: I am still hesitating to grant RW access to the websites dir themselves. Would anybody know if it is OK to give RW access to all directories of a website? => "semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t site_dir" then "restorecon -v site_dir"